# Using HTML href="" on section of URL string

Tags: html, href

I have a URL `www.foo.com/bar/hello/world` Can I use `href=` in such as way:

`<a href = "/hello/world"> LinkText </a>`

In other words, because of the versioning repository I use for work, only the sublink `/hello/world` of the final URL will the same when I push the site live.

Comment: yes. your url must be from the root with out root for example : www.s.com/hello/world

Comment: You might find the `<base>` tag useful. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1889076/is-it-recommended-to-use-the-base-html-tag)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[For reference, see the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XUL/Attribute/href)

However, in `href`, you can either use an absolute URL, such as `https://www.foo.com/bar.html` or, relative, something like `/bar.html`, where `/` refers to the webserver root (but not webserver's system root), or, you can use `bar.html` which points to a file in the same directory level.

Basically you want to have a `/hello/world` link, it will point to `www.foo.com/hello/world`.

If you want it `www.foo.com/hello/world` to point at `www.foo.com/bar/hello/world`, you can either rewrite the URL on the server, or, redirect the users to `www.foo.com/bar/hello/world`

For URL rewriting, see your appropriate webserver docs

Answer (score 1):

Only if the source code is located in 'http://www.foo.com/bar' and then it needs to be going to a valid file extension to execute an action:

```
<a href="/hello/world.html">LinksText</a>
```